# What am I doing wrong in this plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot geom_area as below.

```
natural_prods %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = WEEK_NUM, y = SPEND, fill = HSHD_COMPOSITION)) +
  geom_area()
```

But my output looks like this. Can anyone help me understand why this could be happening? I'm trying to see the pattern in which households of different size(HSHD_COMPOSITION) spend over time(WEEK_NUM).

Sample Data

```
 SPEND  HSHD_COMPOSITION    WEEK_NUM
1.99    Single Female       1
4.79    2 Adults and Kids   1
1.98    1 Adult and Kids    2
7.73    NA                  1
2.15    1 Adult and Kids    3
3.99    2 Adults and Kids   1
1.57    1 Adult and Kids    3
8                      NA   4
5.99    2 Adults and Kids   5
4.99    2 Adults and Kids   4
5.16    Single Female       6
1.39    Single Male         7
1.5            NA           3
0.79    2 Adults and Kids   2
0.99    Single Male         6
1.99    2 Adults            4
2.5           NA            5
3.2    2 Adults and Kids    7
1       1 Adult and Kids    8
```

sample data R:

```
structure(list(BASKET_NUM = c("003705", "004612", "009086", "009829", 
"010003", "015787", "019087", "021615", "021712", "023202", "027586", 
"029586", "032961", "033600", "037672", "038300", "048690", "052045", 
"052218", "053068"), SPEND = c(1.75, 11.56, 1.99, 2.79, 4.79, 
6.29, 1.98, 1.49, 14.98, 5.97, 5, 4.99, 7.73, 2.15, 3.99, 1.57, 
8, 5.99, 4.99, 4.99), HSHD_COMPOSITION = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 6L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, NA, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("1 Adult", "1 Adult and Kids", "2 Adults", 
"2 Adults and Kids", "Single Female", "Single Male"), class = "factor"), 
    WEEK_NUM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), COMMODITY = c("PRODUCE", 
    "GROCERY STAPLE", "GROCERY STAPLE", "DAIRY", "FROZEN FOOD", 
    "DAIRY", "PRODUCE", "PRODUCE", "MEAT - BEEF", "GROCERY STAPLE", 
    "DAIRY", "PRODUCE", "MEAT - CHICKEN", "PRODUCE", "FROZEN FOOD", 
    "PRODUCE", "DAIRY", "GROCERY STAPLE", "PRODUCE", "MEAT - PORK"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

[image]

I need my output to look like this

[image]

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but you don't need the dot

Comment: doesn't help :)

Comment: Please create a reproducible example. We don't have your data. Now it is just guesswork.

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample data

Comment: Hi, updated @jay.sf

Comment: Could you describe your expected outcome in more detail?

Comment: @JuliusVainora I have added a reference image

Comment: Still it's a little hard to answer the question because your sample dataset is very small. Perhaps replacing the first line by `natural_prods %>% group_by(WEEK_NUM, HSHD_COMPOSITION) %>% summarise(SPEND = sum(SPEND)) %>%` helps?

Comment: I knew it would not help your problem. I was just mentioning it in case you did not know that you don't have to write the dot when you are piping to the first argument of the RHS function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data set is very small, I went for a stacked barplot with `width = 1`

```
library( ggplot2 )
natural_prods %>% 
  filter( !is.na( HSHD_COMPOSITION ) ) %>%
  group_by( WEEK_NUM, HSHD_COMPOSITION ) %>%
  summarise( total = sum( SPEND ) ) %>%
  ggplot( aes( x = WEEK_NUM, y = total, colour = HSHD_COMPOSITION, fill = HSHD_COMPOSITION ) ) +
  geom_col( width = 1, position = "stack" )
```

[image]